NGRX Store : toast messages handling
I am displaying toast messages to send a code to a user email address. If the user email is not recognized, I display an error toast. If the email is recognized I display a success toast than redirect the user to another page. My problem is that if the error toast gets displayed, then when I enter in a valid email, the success toast does not get displayed instead the error toast is displayed again.
This is my backend API method in .Net Core 8.0 :
public async Task<ResetPasswordODT> SendResetPasswordCode(EmailString emailString)
{
    var resetPasswordODT = new ResetPasswordODT();

    var userFromDb = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(emailString.UserEmail);

    if(userFromDb == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No such user in database");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!userFromDb.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unverified Email");
        }
        else
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int secretNumber = rnd.Next(100000, 1000000);

            var verficationCode = new VerificationCode
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                SecretNumber = secretNumber,
                Email = emailString.UserEmail,
                Expired = false,
            };

            var message = new Message(new string[] { userFromDb.Email }, "Confirmation email code", secretNumber.ToString());

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(message);

            await _databaseContext.Codes.AddAsync(verficationCode);
            await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            resetPasswordODT.Code = secretNumber;

            return resetPasswordODT;
        }
    }
}

This is my NGRX Store facade :
passwordCodeValue$ = this.store.pipe(select(UserSelectors.getPasswordResetCodeValue));
passwordCodeError$ = this.store.pipe(select(UserSelectors.getPasswordResetCodeError));

constructor(private store: Store<fromUser.UserPartialState>) { }

sendPasswordCode(emailString:EmailString){
    this.store.dispatch(sendPasswordResetCode({emailString}))
}

And this is my component template :
<p-toast [life]="2000"></p-toast>

<form #verificationForm="ngForm">
    <div>
        <h3>Enter in your email address : </h3>
    </div>
    
    <input type="text" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="emailAddress" placeholder="email" required email>
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors?.['required']">Email is required</span>
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors?.['email']">Incorrect email format</span>
    
    
    <p-button type="button" (click)="validateEmail()">Validate Email</p-button>
    <div style="display:inline; margin:10px"></div>
    <p-button type="button" (click)="resetPassword()">Reset Password</p-button>


</form>

And this is my component logic :

resetPassword(){
    if(this.verificationForm.invalid){
      return
    }
    const emailString : EmailString = {
      userEmail:this.emailAddress
    }
    this.userFacade.sendPasswordCode(emailString);

    this.messageService.clear();
    const subscriptionForPasswordCode = new Subscription();
    const subscriptionForPasswordCodeError = new Subscription();


    subscriptionForPasswordCode.add(this.code$.subscribe({
      next:(rcg:PasswordResetOdt | undefined)=>{
        if(rcg?.code !==null && rcg?.code !==undefined){
          console.log(rcg?.code)
          this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Please verify your email inbox !' });
          subscriptionForPasswordCode.unsubscribe();
        }          
      },
      complete:()=>{
        subscriptionForPasswordCode.unsubscribe();
      }
  }))

    subscriptionForPasswordCodeError.add(this.codeError$.subscribe({
      next:(err:Error | undefined)=>{
        if(err!==undefined){
          this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Oops, an error occured !' });
          subscriptionForPasswordCodeError.unsubscribe();
        }

      }
    }));
  }

I tried creating subscriptions and unsubscribing right after the toast message gets displayed but it didn't work.
